# Understanding example code from Think Python How to Think Like a Computer Scientist 4.3 ex 5

Tags: python

I am having a difficult time understanding why the author of the book used some lines of code:

```
import math
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()

def polyline(t, n, length, angle):
    """Draws n line segments.

    t: Turtle object
    n: number of line segments
    length: length of each segment
    angle: degrees between segments
    """
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)


def polygon(t, n, length):
    """Draws a polygon with n sides.

    t: Turtle
    n: number of sides
    length: length of each side.
    """
    angle = 360.0/n
    polyline(t, n, length, angle)


def arc(t, r, angle):
    """Draws an arc with the given radius and angle.

    t: Turtle
    r: radius
    angle: angle subtended by the arc, in degrees
    """
    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * abs(angle) / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 4) + 3
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n

    # making a slight left turn before starting reduces
    # the error caused by the linear approximation of the arc
    t.lt(step_angle/2)
    polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)
    t.rt(step_angle/2)


def circle(t, r):
    """Draws a circle with the given radius.

    t: Turtle
    r: radius
    """
    arc(t, r, 90)

circle(bob, 100)
```

I put in comments highlighting what I was confused on.  The instructions are to make a general function to draw a circle using the turtle in Python. I am using Python 3.7 but I don't really think that makes a difference. Why does the author use the n where I put the first comment? Where did he get that formula from? Also what is the logic behind the rest of the commented code? I understand the rest of the exercises and I would understand this one if I know how he got that equation.

Comment: Does this code work correctly?

Comment: "I am using Python 3.7 but I don't really think that makes a difference" - in this code - yes. "Why does the author use the n ..." - you can name it like you want. "Where did he get that formula from" - propably from own brain if from somewhere, than first author did it. "Also what is the logic behind the rest of the commented code" - no idea what do you mean by this.

Comment: I guess you mean by last question - how exactly work the used functions - you can look in the imported library code to understand it  but usually it's waste of time - libraries are made to not reinvent the wheel and to code faster.

Comment: I think the formula is somewhat arbitrary.  He's just deciding how many steps to break his drawing of an arc into.  Something like "I want to draw the arc in increments of distance 4, but I also want to make sure I use at least 3 steps".

Comment: For the second part, I expect he came up with that through a little trial and error.  He saw that the results weren't quite right, and added the extra bit of turn to have things come out better.  That's often done in programming.  A normal place this is done is when you hit numeric precision issues, like here.

Comment: This is all just my opinion...my guess.  Nobody can know what's in a programmers head without asking him/her.

Comment: Yes I just thought this was some mathematical formula that should be used in constructing circles. So I guess it was just trial and error.

Comment: This is where programming is cool.  It doesn't cost you anything to try things.  Look at the 'n' values that are coming from that formula...put in a print statement.  Then try setting it to hard-coded values to see what that does to the result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no one right answer for 'n'.  It's just going to determine the smoothness of the circle.  I think his formula is attempting to adjust the number of steps so that the circle is about as smooth for different radius values.

Comment: On the second part, the author's comments tell you that what he's doing is kinda a "hack" to make up for limitations in the math. - in fact, I get more what he's saying.  Because he's drawing straight lines instead of curves, there is going to be some approximation error...you are going to go further than if you drew a curve with the same length.  He's somehow making up for that. I think he's causing the line to go a little outside the radius to make the circle a little bigger so that the lengths work out better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the arc function line by line:

```
arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * abs(angle) / 360
```

`2 * math.pi * r` is the formula for the circumference of a circle. `abs(angle) / 360` tells you what proportion of the circle's circumference your path will be. Multiplying them together, you get the distance your turtle will need to travel to describe this arc (assuming it can move along a curved path, which we are only approximating).

```
n = int(arc_length / 4) + 3
```

This is the number of steps we want the turtle to take while we are approximating the path described by the circumference of this circle. It needn't be this particular value; other implementations use `int(arc_length / 3) + 1` and other values. `step_length` and `step_angle` are both scaled by it, so increasing it will make each step smaller and give the individual step a smaller rotation. Ignoring issues of floating point math and accrued rounding errors, the total distance traveled and the total rotation will be unchanged.

```
step_length = arc_length / n
step_angle = float(angle) / n
```

Our polyline will be making `n` steps for us. At each step, we want to travel `1/n`th of the `arc_length` and rotate `1/n`th of the total angle our arc describes. If we make `n` a larger value in the line before these two, `step_length` and `step_angle` will be scaled down correspondingly.

As for the rest:

```
t.lt(step_angle/2)
polyline(t, n, step_length, step_angle)  # take a lot of little steps
t.rt(step_angle/2)
```

The half turn here is a small improvement in our approximation of the arc. Think about the path we are describing here for, say, a 90 degree arc along the unit circle starting at (1, 0) and ending at (0, 1) with 3 steps. Below is a table of values for locations on the unit circle itself (ideal x, ideal y, and ideal heading, where ideal heading is the tangent of the circle at that point), raw x, raw y, and raw heading, and the x, y, and heading yielded by making a `step_angle/2` left turn before starting the path and then a `step_angle/2` right turn afterward to cancel it out:

```
     |ideal x|ideal y|ideal heading|raw x|raw y|raw heading|adj x|adj y|adj heading|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start|1      |0      |90           |1    |0    |90         |1    |0    |105        |
Step1|0.86   |0.5    |120          |1    |0.52 |120        |0.86 |0.51 |135        |
Step2|0.5    |0.86   |150          |0.74 |0.98 |150        |0.49 |0.88 |165        |
Step3|0      |1      |180          |0.28 |1.24 |180        |-0.01|1.01 |195        |
End  |0      |1      |180          |0.28 |1.24 |180        |-0.01|1.01 |180        |
```

Note that the adjusted values are much closer to the ideal values than the raw ones. This makes intuitive sense when you consider how polyline works: it moves forward in whatever direction it is facing and then makes a left turn. When you start with the unadjusted heading, you move `step_length` above the arc before you even try to make a turn. You'll always be above and to the right of the arc. By taking a half step_angle turn to the left first, you'll spend some of each `step_length` under the arc, and some of each `step_length` above the arc. This will yield a better approximation of the arc than one which is strictly outside it.

**EDIT**:

As to the problem with your updated circle method, it takes two parameters (the turtle and the radius of the circle) and then calls arc accordingly right now your implementation is:

```
def circle(t, r):
    arc(t, r, 90)
```

Where `arc`'s third parameter is the angle of the arc you wish to travel. To make a circle, you need 360 degrees though, not 90.

Comment: hell of an answer! :)